# Why is the image colour not showing with RGB?

Tags: python-3.x, image

I run the code to show the latent space images, but the colour of the image is not displayed as RGB. If you know, would you tell me what is the cause of this result? I would like to output each image like

[image]

The problem code and result are

```
random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(10, 128))
generator = make_generator(128)

images = generator(random_latent_vectors)
images *= 255

images = images.numpy()
images.shape

plt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
for i in range(images.shape[0]):
  plt.subplot(2, 5, i+1)
  plt.imshow(images[i, :, :, 0].astype("int32"))
  plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

`generator` is built from

```
def make_generator(latent_dim):
  model = keras.Sequential([
                            keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,)),
                            layers.Dense(8 * 8 * 128),
                            layers.Reshape((8, 8, 128)),
                            layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
                            layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),

                            layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
                            layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                            
                            layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
                            layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                            layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=5, padding="same", activation="sigmoid")
                            ])
  return model
```